# Enable/Disable a <script> using another script or a code in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I got the following situation:

I need to add a bundle (not done defined by me), because there is a bootstrap problem in my PartialView. Being so, I tried to define a condition to use Scripts.Render() as the following example:

```
@if (TypeOfUserModel.Financial == usu.TypeId)
     {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
     }
```

It kind of that solved the problem to type of users that I have in my program, but the user "Financial" still having the same problem. I though in disable the script after the piece of code that I wanted executed, but I didn't find a way of doing it in .NET, so I though of doing with JavaScript, doing a RenderFormat in C#, definig an Id to the script and using a disabled class (as shown below), but it didn't work.

```
@if (TypeOfUserModel.Financial == usu.TypeId)
     {
        @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type='text/javascript' src='{0}' id='yay' 
                              class='disabled'></script>","~/bundles/bootstrap")
     }
```

Do you think that it can be done? If it can't... Why?

Comment: Render if you need it, don't render it if you don't need it. Keep it simple.

Comment: @mason , I need to render for a kind of profile, but if I render to that profile, another funcionality is lost in the same page. That's why I need to enable to a certain piece of code and, after that, disable it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to have your code dependent on a flag. For example:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script>var shouldRun = {0};</script>", someBooleanFlag.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
```

Then, on the actual script:

```
<script>if (shouldRun) { ... }</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! So, how would that flag work? Because the RenderFormat must receive a path to my bundle.